# Why do i get "wrong number of output arguments" error when converting from Matlab to Scilab?

Tags: matlab, scilab

I'm trying to covert this Matlab code to Scilab, but I have some problems.

```
N = 101;
L = 4*pi;
x = linspace(0,L,N);
% It has three data set; 1: past, 2: current, 3: future.
u = zeros(N,3);
s = 0.5;
% Gaussian Pulse
y = 2*exp(-(x-L/2).^2);
u(:,1) = y;
u(:,2) = y;
% Plot the initial condition.
handle_line = plot(x,u(:,2),'LineWidth',2);
axis([0,L,-2,2]);
xlabel('x'); ylabel('u');
title('Wave equation');
% Dirichet Boundary conditions
u(1,:) = 0;
u(end,:) = 0;
filename = 'wave.gif';
for ii=1:100
    disp(['at ii= ', num2str(ii)]);
    u(2:end-1,3) = s*(u(3:end,2)+u(1:end-2,2)) ...
        + 2*(1-s)*u(2:end-1,2) ...
        - u(2:end-1,1);
    u(:,1) = u(:,2);
    u(:,2) = u(:,3);
    handle_line.YData = u(:,2);
    drawnow;
    frame = getframe(gcf);
    im = frame2im(frame);
    [A,map] = rgb2ind(im,256);
    if ii==1
           imwrite(A,map,filename,'gif','LoopCount',Inf,'DelayTime',0.05);
    else
        imwrite(A,map,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append','DelayTime',0.05);
    end
end
```

I get an error for this line:

```
handle_line = plot(x,u(:,2),'LineWidth',2);
```

Error states: Wrong number of output arguments

What should i change to fix it?

Comment: Unlike MATLAB, in Scilab most graphics commands do not returns outputs.  After creating a graphics object you need to use the [get](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.3.3/en_US/get.html) function to retrieve the handle.  Once obtained, you can manipulate its properties in the manner shown in the example at the above link, and perhaps in your case the [polyline](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.3.3/en_US/polyline_properties.html) object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
N = 101;
L = 4*pi;
x = linspace(0,L,N);
% It has three data set; 1: past, 2: current, 3: future.
u = zeros(N,3);
s = 0.5;
% Gaussian Pulse
y = 2*exp(-(x-L/2).^2);
u(:,1) = y;
u(:,2) = y;
% Define a standard plot range for x and y
x_range=[min(x) max(x)];
y_range=[-max(y) max(y)];
% Plot the initial condition.
plot(x,u(:,2),'LineWidth',2);
axis([0,L,-2,2]);
xlabel('x'); ylabel('u');
title('Wave equation');
% Dirichet Boundary conditions
u(1,:) = 0;
u(end,:) = 0;
filename = 'wave.gif';
for ii=1:100
    disp(['at ii= ', num2str(ii)]);
    u(2:end-1,3) = s*(u(3:end,2)+u(1:end-2,2)) ...
        + 2*(1-s)*u(2:end-1,2) ...
        - u(2:end-1,1);
    u(:,1) = u(:,2);
    u(:,2) = u(:,3);
    plot(x,u(:,2),'LineWidth',2);
    axis([x_range y_range]);
    frame = getframe(gcf);
    im = frame2im(frame);
    [A,map] = rgb2ind(im,256);
    if ii==1
           imwrite(A,map,filename,'gif','LoopCount',Inf,'DelayTime',0.05);
    else
        imwrite(A,map,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append','DelayTime',0.05);
    end
end
```

I removed the output and added axis limit independently.

Comment: I think there was a minor problem with my code. Try this out. Hope it help now...

Comment: Thank you. It seems like it solved the problem. But now i get an error: undefined variable: axis in line 16. Do you know how could i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```matlab
axis([0,L,-2,2]);
```

has to be translated in Scilab to

```
set(gca(),"data_bounds",[0,L,-2,2]);
```